# Using normal SQL with Active Records in Code Igniter

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I have a single normal SQL statement in the middle of my Active Records query. Is there any way I can 'add' this query to the AR one without having two independent queries? The SQL is as follows if someone would help me 'convert' it into Active Records-style in case it doesn't work.

```
SELECT birthday
FROM usertable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y')
BETWEEN $minimumDate AND $maximumDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$this->db
    ->select('birthday')
    ->where("STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN $minimumDate AND $maximumDate")
    ->get('usertable');
```

But you will have to escape the variables yourself in this case.

You *could* also do this:

```
$this->db
    ->select('birthday')
    ->where("STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y') >", $minimumDate)
    ->where("STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y') <", $maximumDate)
    ->get('usertable');
```

This will automatically escape the second parameter of `where()`, but now we're running `STR_TO_DATE()` twice and have a slightly less elegant query (not using `BETWEEN`).

Active Record can be difficult to use MySQL functions with. Sometimes it's best to just do the query manually if you are not building it dynamically. CI offers some methods of doing this easily while escaping your input properly for you.

See the section in the user guide about [Query Bindings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html):

```
$sql = "SELECT birthday
FROM usertable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y')
BETWEEN ? AND ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array($minimumDate, $maximumDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
SELECT birthday
FROM usertable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d.%m.%Y')
BETWEEN $minimumDate AND $maximumDate
```

by chaining like this -

```
$this->db->select('birthday')->from('usertable')->where('STR_TO_DATE', '%d.%m.%Y')->limit($minimumDate, $maximumDate);
```

Comment: This is not how ActiveRecord's `where()` works, or how MySQL's `BETWEEN` works. Have you tried this? What query did it actually create?

Comment: Well, i haven't used the query :|
I should've tried before posing. but this is the way it is given in the userguide

Comment: And `where('STR_TO_DATE', '%d.%m.%Y')` part would be wrong. But i don't know what it would be.

Comment: The `limit()` and `where()` in your example are off. This will produce something like `SELECT birthday FROM usertable WHERE STR_TO_DATE = '%d.%m.%Y' LIMIT $minimumDate, $maximumDate`